# Let JS execute a function, by loading another html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two html files `first.html` and `second.html`. Both are using a file `main.js`. So lets pretend I am in the `second.html` and I want to change the `window.location.href` to `first.html`. But the same time, I want to call a function, which should be executed in the `first.html` file just after it is loaded from the second file. So how should I do this. How can I check, from which page the `first.html` file was called to load?

If I will use the following code,

```
$(document).ready(function() {...});
```

The function would be loaded every time, I load this page. But I want to execute the function just, when the page is loaded from the second.html file.

Hope you understand my question.

Comment: how do you load your second.html page from first.html page? Through a link or by js action? or vice versa

Answer (score 1):

You can check the url of the page. window.location.href should get you the url, which you can determine which page you're in.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so you want to load the function only when the `first.html` is loaded from `second.html`. You can use [localstorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) or [cookies](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) to store the name of the page.

then use an if statement to check if the cookie is equal let's say to your previous page name then load the function. Then reset the cookie/delete it. Local storage does similar things too but according to w3 schools, they are better than cookies. I don't trust that site much though.